# Transit between T3 to T2 at DXB Dubai Airport

Tags: airports, airport-transfer

My wife with an infant is arriving at Dubai airport at 07:50am on an Emirates, then travelling further to Faisalabad on FlyDubai from terminal 2 at 11.40am. Will her luggage be transferred automatically to that flight? And where will she get her boarding card from for FlyDubai? Somebody please reply thank you.

Comment: It depends. If the flights are on one ticket, luggage will be transferred, and she gets two boarding passes when checking first in. Two tickets, no, she's on her own. That's independant of Dubai or Emirates.